# How to auto generate a webpage after user submits form

Tags: database, templates, joomla, auto-generate

I am looking for some initial direction on this one because I cannot seem to find my way with it.  Let me explain...

I am developing a website wherein a logged in site member (Joomla 1.6) can fill out a simple form and attach a pdf to be uploaded upon submission.  The user then clicks the submit button and the page will refresh to a new and unique web page.

User Submits data on http://www.examplesite.com and then after submission a new web page is generated that is called http://www.examplesite.com/userSubmittedValue

This newly generated web page would come from a template that is specified by the administrator and, most important, it will display all of the information that the user submitted.  Also, there would be a link to download the pdf they uploaded.  The user could then view a list of all the pages they have created in this manner via their profile.

I have seen this all over, but I am at a loss for how to generate this.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you will be able to easily do or get a detailed answer for here. If you just wanted to do the submission form with a thank you page that shows the data submitted you could use any number of form wizard type extensions - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

If you just needed a way for users to upload PDfs and have access to them you could use one of the file management extensions that offer front end upload features - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads

If the additional data that is being submitted is simply data related to the file - title, description, etc then one of the file download components should work fine for you. The choices are limited in 1.6 at this time though so you might have to go with 1.5 to get the extension that works best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So this probably isn't the best way to do it if your using Joomla but it just might help.

I would use PHP and inside of you're directory have a file like "template.html". Then I would create some php to handle the task of....

1. Opening "template.html"
2. Finding and replacing the values that the user passed you
3. Save the "template.html" under a new name (userSubmittedValue.html)

Again, I never really use Joomla. If you were to try this I'd suggest checking out php's file system functions (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Hope this helps a bit.